# String.replace() with regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, str-replace

I'm having difficulty getting String.replace() to work with JavaScript. It returns in console TypeError: url is undefined

```
var url = $(this).attr("href");
var id  = url.replace(/(^.{4})(&remove=1)/, "");
console.log(id);
```

Comment: console.log(url) to see what it is.

Comment: javascript or jquery?

Comment: @Mika it's the same output. url is undefined.

Comment: @Tushar i'm using jquery

Comment: And what's your question? Isn't the error message clear? Apparently `this` doesn't have a `href` attribute,

Comment: `var url = $(this).attr("href")||"";` will remove type errors.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery statement $(this).attr("href") is returning undefined.

Thats why it says url is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is TypeError: url is undefined, it means that "$(this).attr("href");" returns undefined. Your regular expression is ok.

Try outputin the content of this, $(this) and $(this).attr("href"). You'll see where the problem is (your whole selector may be broken, or you may select an element that just does not have the "href" attribute).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that either `this` is not a DOM object or if it is a DOM object, then it doesn't have an `href` attribute.  Here's the logic and simple test app that leads to that conclusion.

Your error means that `url` is undefined.  Since `url` is the product of `$(this).attr("href")`, we have to figure out how that expression can be undefined.

As long as you have jQuery installed, then `$(this)` can't be undefined and if it was, you'be getting a different error about referencing the `.attr()` method.  So, we can assume that `$(this)` must be a valid jQuery object.

So, it appears that you either have an empty jQuery object or that the `this` element does not have an `href` attribute.

Running a quick [jsFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tWYPz/) shows that either condition will result in `url` being undefined.  So, you have to figure out whether `this` is not a DOM object or whether your DOM object doesn't' have the `href` attribute.  It's one of those two causes.

Here's the test code:

```
// all  of these tests print "undefined" to the console

// a DOM object that doesn't have the href attribute because
// #test is just an ordinary div
var url = $("#test").attr("href");
console.log(url);

// an empty jQuery object because #foo doesn't exist
url = $("#foo").attr("href");
console.log(url);

// a non DOM object in the jQuery object
url = $({}).attr("href");
console.log(url);
```

You can debug this more yourself by doing this:

```
console.log("begin marker");
console.log(this);
console.log(this.href);
var url = $(this).attr("href")
console.log(url);
console.log("end marker");
```

And, then report back what those `console.log()` statements show.

Comment: I tried this code: var url = $(this).attr("href"); console.log(url); and I get 2 outputs. undefined and the string I want.

Comment: How can you get two outputs?  You only show one `console.log()` statement.  Is this code getting called twice, once with a valid input and once with an invalid input?  I don't understand what point you're making.  I've explained that either `this` isn't a DOM object or if it is, it doesn't have an `href` attribute.  You need to figure out which of these two possibilities is the issue.  You haven't shown us enough code/html for us to have any idea which of the two issues it is so you either have to troubleshoot that yourself or show us more of your code/HTML.

Comment: @user1408643 - I've added some debugging suggestions to the end of my answer.